# Typescript reference comment for working

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 4 and Typescript.

I have a class like MyClass.ts:

```
/// <reference path="interfaces/IMyClass"/>
export = MyModule;

module MyModule {
class MyClass {
    constructor(myObject: IMyClass){....}
    ...
}
}
```

And another MyInterface.ts:

```
export = MyModule;

module MyModule {

interface IMyClass {
    ...
}
}
```

VS2013 is not acknowledging the IMyClass reference in the MyClass file (no intellisense either), but the reference is acting like VS can see it (no red underlines saying it can't find the file).

If I change the interface filename to MyInterface.d.ts, it does the same thing.

If I change the interface inside MyInterface.d.ts to this:

```
//export = MyModule ;

declare module MyModule {

interface IMyClass {
    ...
}
}
```

it fails as well.

If I change the interface inside MyInterface.d.ts to this:

```
//export = MyInterfaces ;

declare module MyInterfaces {

interface IMyClass {
    ...
}
}
```

it works.

Am I missing something?  So we can only use reference comments for .d.ts files and the exported module names can be the same??

I'm finding a lot of the stuff around modules in typescript to be confusing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> VS2013 is not acknowledging the IMyClass reference in the MyClass file (no intellisense either),

The modules `MyModule` between two TypeScript files that use *external modules* are distinct. And therefore you don't get `interface IMyClass` available in the second files `MyModule`.

Tip: You might want to review *internal* vs. *external* modules in TypeScript (hint: don't use internal ones if you are using external modules). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: Thanks, I have been using the Typescript language spec for reference.  I see in 2.3 "Interfaces, enums, and internal modules are "open ended," meaning that interface, enum, and internal
module declarations with the same qualified name relative to a common root are automatically merged.", but I don't see anything saying external modules can't act the same.  Are external modules not open-ended?